# Pivotal server is hanging when trying to start

Tags: spring-tool-suite, tcserver

The computer is Windows7 64bit Family Edition. I unzipped the downloaded Spring-Tool-Suite 3.8.1 , there are jdk 1.8 and jre 1.6 , java_home is on jre 1.6 because the Spring project java runtime build path is 1.6

I imported a project , built it and dragged it into the pivotal server. But when I started the pivotal server by clicking the green start button then it is always mentionned "starting" through 2 minutes , then an alert error is shown. So how to make the server start ?

Comment: first of all, you don't need to setup JAVA_HOME to a specific JDK in order to have your projects use that inside of STS/Eclipse. You can configure multiple JREs/JDKs and let projects use whatever they need. But I am not sure your issue with the server is related to that. What does the error message say? In addition, is there anything in the Error Log view that might be related and could reveal more details?

Comment: there is nothing displayed in the error log tab even in the problems tab.

Comment: I vaguely guess that you are trying to run the tc-server with that 1.6 JRE and that it isn't compatible with that old Java version anymore. You can configure the JRE or JDK that should be used in Eclipse/STS to run the tc-server in the "Server -> Runtime Environment" preferences. Can you try that, just to make sure tc-server runs on top of a JDK 1.8 ?

Comment: you  could also try to start the server from the command line (outside of Eclipse/STS), just to see if that works fine or not, and if not, if it reveals more details about the problem.